# Count items in a date range in R

Tags: r

I have DF, with unique ID's and TYPE, and I intend, from an interval between dates (DT_STARD and DT_END), to search and count how many times they appear. This is my `DF_1`:

```
ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444)
TYPE <- c('A1','A1','B1','B1','A1','B1')
DT_START <- c(as.Date(c('2022/07/20','2022/07/18','2022/07/10','2022/07/05','2022/07/03','2022/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DT_END <- c(as.Date(c('2021/07/20','2021/07/18','2021/07/10','2021/07/05','2021/07/03','2021/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID,TYPE,DT_START,DT_END)
```

And I want to look up the date range in that `DF_2`:

```
ID <- c(111,111,111,111,222,222,444,444,444)
TYPE <- c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','B1','B1')
DT <- c(as.Date(c('2022/06/01','2022/05/15','2022/01/01','2021/06/01','2022/03/02','2021/12/21','2021/12/29','2022/06/30','2022/06/15') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DF_2 <- data.frame(ID,TYPE,DT)
```

And this is the result I want to get:

```
ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444)
TYPE <- c('A1','A1','B1','B1','A1','B1')
DT_START <- c(as.Date(c('2022/07/20','2022/07/18','2022/07/10','2022/07/05','2022/07/03','2022/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DT_END <- c(as.Date(c('2021/07/20','2021/07/18','2021/07/10','2021/07/05','2021/07/03','2021/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
COUNT <- c(3,2,0,0,1,2)
DF_3 <- data.frame(ID,TYPE,DT_START,DT_END,COUNT)
```

How do I look up and count a from a date range?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, how the output in DF_3 is coming ?  Can you share your coding efforts and where you are having problems?

Comment: I think you changed around DT_START AND DT_END in your DF_1 data frame (the start dates are later than the end dates)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join` from package `dplyr` for this, then creating a indicator and summarise that:

```
library(dplyr)

ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444)
TYPE <- c('A1','A1','B1','B1','A1','B1')
DT_END <- c(as.Date(c('2022/07/20','2022/07/18','2022/07/10','2022/07/05','2022/07/03','2022/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DT_START <- c(as.Date(c('2021/07/20','2021/07/18','2021/07/10','2021/07/05','2021/07/03','2021/07/01') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID,TYPE,DT_START,DT_END)

ID <- c(111,111,111,111,222,222,444,444,444)
TYPE <- c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','B1','B1')
DT <- c(as.Date(c('2022/06/01','2022/05/15','2022/01/01','2021/06/01','2022/03/02','2021/12/21','2021/12/29','2022/06/30','2022/06/15') ,"%Y/%m/%d"))
DF_2 <- data.frame(ID,TYPE,DT)

#left join the data frames
left_join(DF_1, DF_2) %>%
  #determine if DT is outside of DT_START and DT_END. If so, or NA, assign 0, else assign 1 
  mutate(in_range = ifelse(is.na(DT) | (DT <= DT_START & DT >= DT_END), yes = 0, no = 1)) %>%
  #group by and summarise
  group_by(ID, TYPE, DT_START, DT_END) %>%
  summarise(COUNT = sum(in_range)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  as.data.frame

#>    ID TYPE   DT_START     DT_END COUNT
#> 1 111   A1 2021-07-20 2022-07-20     4
#> 2 222   A1 2021-07-18 2022-07-18     2
#> 3 222   B1 2021-07-10 2022-07-10     0
#> 4 333   B1 2021-07-05 2022-07-05     0
#> 5 444   A1 2021-07-03 2022-07-03     1
#> 6 444   B1 2021-07-01 2022-07-01     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. The main difference with @VvdL solution is the use of `drop` argument inside `group_by` to avoid dropping groups without observations when performing the `filter`. These groups will later contain zeros in the `COUNT` column.

```
library(dplyr)

DF_1 |>
  # Join with DF1 using ID and TYPE columns
  left_join(DF_2, 
            by =c("ID", "TYPE")) |>
  # Group by ID and TYPE, DT_End and DT_START so these columns
  # are mantained in the summarise
  # Add drop = F to avoid removing groups without any observation
  # after the filter
  group_by(ID, TYPE, DT_END,DT_START, .drop = F) |>
  # Filter for condition of interest
  filter(DT >= DT_END & DT <= DT_START) |>
  # Count
  summarise(COUNT = n())

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID, TYPE, DT_END [6]
#     ID TYPE  DT_END     DT_START   COUNT
#  <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>     <int>
#1   111 A1    2021-07-20 2022-07-20     3
#2   222 A1    2021-07-18 2022-07-18     2
#3   222 B1    2021-07-10 2022-07-10     0
#4   333 B1    2021-07-05 2022-07-05     0
#5   444 A1    2021-07-03 2022-07-03     1
#6   444 B1    2021-07-01 2022-07-01     2
```